# Ubuntu server 20.04 netplan multiple IP addresses on one network card

Tags: 20.04

I have some real issues with one brand new Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I'm trying to accomplish simple network configuration - one physical interface with 2 different IP addresses from the same network using the same gateway. I see netplan is not supporting aliases anymore so I was following the recommendation from netplan page. Here is my config:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
     addresses:
       - 192.168.1.100/24
       - 192.168.1.99/24
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
         addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
```

So when I netplan apply server disappears from the network completely. By looking in the syslog i see the following error:

enp2s0: Could not set route: Nexthop has invalid gateway. Network is unreachable
enp2s0: Failed

I was following the examples from here https://netplan.io/examples#using-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface
This should be very simple configuration which I don't understand why not working. Am I missing something?
Thanks,
Andrey

here is an output from netplan debug:

```
srv1:~$ sudo netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: Generating output files..
** (generate:1744): DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:1744): GLib-DEBUG: 11:04:55.637: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

Comment: You only have one .yaml file in /etc/netplan, correct? enp2s0 is your ethernet interface, yes? If you're using my exact .yaml, what happens after a `sudo netplan apply` and `reboot`?

Comment: output is the same as above however after restart it started working. I'm little bit confused as doesn't work unless restarted. Even sudo systemctl restart system-networkd doesn't bring the network up.

Comment: Reboot required due to the static IPs... as per my instructions. Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Netplan is very fussy about spacing, indentation, and no tabs.

Try this slight variation of your .yaml file...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.100/24
        - 192.168.1.99/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Thank you for this. Although my config was applied after `sudo netplan apply`. No need for me to reboot for it to work. (On Ubuntu 20.04)